# How do I get all requests to a bucket in S3 to redirect to corresponding requests to another bucket in S3?

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm hosting a static website using Amazon's S3 file storage web service. The bucket I'm hosting it on is "www.dleybz.com" (to which I own the corresponding domain name). I also have the bucket "dleybz.com" set up on my account, and it's set to redirect requests to the index of the original bucket.

Unfortunately, it's redirecting all request to the root of the original bucket. So while "www.dleybz.com/reddit.html" redirects to where it's supposed to, "dleybz.com/reddit.html" just redirects to "www.dleybz.com/index.html", whereas I would want it to redirect to "www.dleybz.com/reddit.html".

One solution would be to simply clone all the files in the original bucket and store them in the second bucket, but this has disadvantages (having to upload to two buckets instead of just one every time a change is made, having to store twice as much data).

Another would be to set up a corresponding redirection file, but that would require creating a new redirect html file for each file in the original bucket, which would be time-consuming.

[This Amazon guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) instructs users to simply select the "Redirect all requests to another host name" option and enter the name to direct users to. I've done this, but it results in the problem I'm currently having: all requests redirect to the root domain, instead of the corresponding web-address.

Answer (score 2):

"Redirect all requests to another hostname" does *exactly* what you are wanting.

However, DNS has to be correctly configured to actually send the request to the S3 bucket.  In your case, that's the problem -- you aren't actually sending requests for that hostname to S3.  You're sending them somewhere else.  The following response is clearly not from S3:

```
$ curl -v dleybz.com/random/path/here.html
* About to connect() to dleybz.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 216.239.32.21... connected
> GET /random/path/here.html HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: dleybz.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: http://www.dleybz.com
< Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 21:56:39 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Server: ghs
< Content-Length: 218
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
<
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.dleybz.com">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host dleybz.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

This looks more like you're doing some kind of domain redirect using (I'm speculating, based on the response) [Google Domains Redirection](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141?hl=en).

Your DNS isn't currently hosted by Route 53.  That's essentially a requirement (technical, not policy) for using a bucket at the apex of a domain, because `CNAME` records aren't allowed at the zone apex. Route 53 has a built-in integration capability called `Alias` records allowing this mapping without `CNAME` records -- you need to configure those and switch your DNS provider to Route 53, consistent with sections 3 and 4 of the tutorial you've linked to in the question.

---

Note also that with a little command line hackery to force the request to be sent to S3 instead of wherever it's currently going, you can prove that the bucket *is* working as it should -- it's just that requests aren't arriving.

We'll send a request to the S3 website endpoint in us-east-1 and rewrite the `Host:` header:

```
$ curl -v -H 'Host: dleybz.com' http://s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/random/path/here.html
* About to connect() to s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 54.231.9.252... connected
> GET /random/path/here.html HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Accept: */*
> Host: dleybz.com
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< x-amz-id-2: bS9KJJ28qo+AVoxGWwLdavXilX+HFe4suNFdlJsFVfoJl/gFTb/eIToafnjpKLLw4syaYG9jaF0=
< x-amz-request-id: 0090A3CCCCC7AD2A
< Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 22:14:12 GMT
< Location: http://www.dleybz.com/random/path/here.html
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: AmazonS3
<
* Connection #0 to host s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Note that the redirect works as expected with the path preserved, when the request actually goes to S3.